# Automatic Link to GitHub Pages URL from README.md?

Tags: github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

Is there a way to create a link to a repository's GitHub page in the repository's README.md (or other Markdown file) without hardcoding the URL?

The use case I'm facing is the result of forking a repository in which the README includes `[a link](https://their-org.github.io/repo/)`, and which I'd rather not have to manually update to `[a link](https://my-org.github.io/repo/)`.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to capture the URL in the content available at `[the page build status report](../../settings/pages/status)`, which takes advantage of relative linking.

Comment: No answer yet? Nobody has a clue?

Comment: The real answer: this is unfortunately not possible (as best I can tell) right now. It'd be great if GitHub added some basic templating capabilities to allow things like user/org/repo/branch to be dynamically inserted into markdown. There are many cases where this would be useful, not just linking to a GitHub Pages url.

Comment: There is this GitHub Action which fills the need, but it has to create a new commit: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/dynamic-readme

Comment: Created a discussion here: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/37122

Answer (score -2):

My readme is `(repo)/blob/master/README.md`

I'm not sure how robust this is, but this test worked for me:

```
test link: [testlink](../../)
```

Is that what you were asking for?

Comment: This produces only a link to the repository view (branches, commits, files), the asker and I looking for a link that points to the web page (serving files like webpages) provided by the configured "GitHub page", usually `<user>.github.com/<repo>`. [About GitHub pages](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-github-pages/)

Comment: And you tried `../../<repo>` ?? I was giving the general solution, or attempting to, anyway :)

Comment: @fyngyrz The relative link you give points to the repository, which is not what I'm trying to do. I want a link to the "GitHub page" (google it) created by the repository. The link in `github.com/<user>/<repo>/blob/master/README.md` must (usually) point to `<user>.github.io/<repo>/index.html`. The different *domain* makes your answer incorrect.

Answer (score -2):

Relative links always works on README.md and in every markdown file in your repo. I'm using them to document a personal project and I've never had an issue with that. Take a look at (https://github.com/andreabenini/bM3tal/blob/master/README.md) plenty of relative links in each part of the project. I'm documenting it with md files because I'm lazy and for a bare doc markdown files are qu

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, @Ben. Read the comments on the other unaccepted answer ... same mistake.